# Как правильно оформить пояснение?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение:

Детали конструктор именует и по их функции, и по подобию формам своего тела — головка, ручка, ножка — и одежды : юбка, фартук, рукав.

Мне кажется, нужно оформить или так:

Детали конструктор именует и по их функции, и по подобию формам своего тела — головка, ручка, ножка — и одежды - юбка, фартук, рукав.

Или со скобками:

Детали конструктор именует и по их функции, и по подобию формам своего тела (головка, ручка, ножка) и одежды (юбка, фартук, рукав).

Как лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант: Детали конструктор именует и по их функции, и по подобию формам своего тела и одежды:  головка, ручка, ножка или юбка, фартук, рукав.

Такой вариант легко читается и воспринимается зрительно, в то время как в остальных случаях сложно применить интонацию вставных конструкций

Comment: Вы хорошо придумали, но если не менять текст так сильно, то варианты с тире или со скобками допустимы? Особенно меня интересует вариант с тире. Потому что так как есть, мне кажется, оставлять нельзя.

Comment: Еще один вариант: Детали конструктор именует и по их функции, и по подобию формам или своего тела - головка, ручка, ножка - или одежды - юбка, фартук, рукав". Тире можно заменить скобками.

Comment: Спасибо. Вариант с тире, мне кажется, лучше всего.

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор именует детали!